# dereferencing structure from (void *) type

Tags: c, void-pointers

i'm trying to pass data with void pointer and then cast it to (pData *) type.
What am i doing wrong?
gcc gives me

gcc test.c error: request for member ‘filename’ in something not a structure or union

```
typedef struct data {
        char *filename;
        int a;
} pData;

void mod_struct(void *data) {
        printf("%s\n",(pData *)data->filename); //error on this line
}

void main() {
        pData *data;
        data = (pData *) malloc(sizeof(pData));
        data->filename = (char *)malloc(100);
        strcpy(data->filename,"testing testing");
        data->a=1;
        mod_struct((void *)&data);
}
```

Comment: casts are rarely needed in C. Your code has 1 good cast (in the line with the error) and 3 erroneous casts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be

```
printf("%s\n", ((pData *) data)->filename);
```

`->` operator has higher precedence than typecast operator.

In addition to that your call to `mod_struct` should look as follows

```
mod_struct((void *) data);
```

That `&` you have there makes absolutely no sense. Why are you taking the address of `data` when `data` is already a pointer to what you need?

Comment: ...or even better, just `mod_struct(data)`.

Answer (score 4):

`(pData *)data->filename` is equivalent to `(pData *)(data->filename)`; add parens if you want it to be `((pData *)data)->filename`.

Also, BTW, your code will crash. You're passing a `pData **` cast to `void *`, and then casting it back to a `pdata *`.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting the pData* to a void* pointer by taking the address of it. so you are actually casting pData** to void*, therefore you need to dereference it properly

```
(*(pData**)data)->filename
```

or simple don't take the address of data when you cast in main

```
mod_struct((void *)data);
```

Comment: You can't dereference a `void *` pointer. If you want to go the first way, they proper code will look as follows: `(*(pData**)data)->filename`. Your current version will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct {  
  char *filename;
  int a;
  }pdata;

void func(void * data)
{
  printf("%s \n",(*(pdata **)data)->filename);

}

int main()
{
  pdata *data;
  void *vptr=0;
  data=(pdata *)malloc(sizeof(pdata));
  data->filename=(char *)malloc(sizeof(50));
  vptr=&data;
  printf("enter the file name \n");
  scanf("%s ",data->filename);
  func(vptr);
  return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[TIPS C CODE]
@Damir:

```
  data=(pdata *)malloc(sizeof(pdata));
```

Should be corrected like this:

```
data = malloc(sizeof(pdata));
```

It is unnecessary, as void * is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type in this case. In one case : portability. It will probably be good but in your case i don't think so, it was just a tips. you can cast if you want but i think is not necessary.

Under the ANSI C standard, the cast is redundan.

Have a good week end.